# Delphi operators ^, what does it mean?

Tags: delphi, operators

I can't find on the internet what ^ operator means.

So what ^ means in this example:

```
P = PChar(s);
While P^ <> #0 do
begin
//do something
end;
```

`#0`is a character that's representing the end of a string for example. But i can't find the ^ on the internet. Can someone please explain?

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Expressions_%28Delphi%29#Operators

Comment: `^^` = cat ears. `:3` = cat smile

Comment: Si i guess P^ is a cat ear with a monocle?

Comment: `P^` could be a left-handed [Maneki-neko](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maneki-neko)

Comment: Haha, yeah surely use a maneki-neko in his code x)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the pointer de-reference operator. In your example code, `P` is a pointer to a character. And so `P^` de-references that pointer. In other words, `P^` evaluates to the character that `P` points to.

The operator is documented here: [Expressions | Pointer Operators](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Expressions_(Delphi)#Pointer_Operators).

> The `^` operator dereferences a pointer. Its operand can be a pointer of any type except the generic Pointer, which must be typecast before dereferencing.

Perhaps a more useful documentation topic for you is here: [Pointers and Pointer Types](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Pointers_and_Pointer_Types_(Delphi)). This latter topic covers pointers in a lot more detail. And you could also usefully read [String Types](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/String_Types_(Delphi)) which covers the special treatment for `PChar`.

Comment: So ^ is the adress in memory? Why would someone compare directly the adress rather than values of variable like normal human being?

Comment: No. P is the address. P^ is the value contained in that address. Be careful about PChar though. Can surprise. P will be implicitly converted to a string if you let it.

Comment: Oh i see i htink. So if for '@' the value in ascii is 64. He would compare 64 with #0 ?

Comment: You can think of it like that. But you can perhaps better think of it as a character comparison, `'@' <> #0`

Comment: What would differencies normal referencing without ^ ? if i compare P <> #0 it owuld be the same as P^ <> 0 if  @ is the response in both cases  isn't it?

Comment: I believe that would convert both operands to a string and that would have completely different meaning. Assuming that when you wrote `P^ <> 0` that was meant to be `P^ <> #0`. What you wrote does not compile.

Comment: It compiles and it's used in a split function. But i just tried something. I made a button and defined P as PChar. Then set P to Pchar('test'); and then i showMEssage(P^); It shows 't' first character of the string. I don't get it now haha that thing is strange.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61985/discussion-between-user28470-and-david-heffernan).

Comment: `P^ <> 0` won't compile I think. As I said, P will be implicitly converted to string if you let it. And passing as arg to function expecting string does that. Now P^ is a character. Just one character. Pass it to a string parameter than that character gets converted to string. Doesn't the documentation explain all this?

Comment: Oh wait i got it! I haven't seen your edit! So basicly it will return the point of a momory block as long as it points to something there no problem but when my P value is empty it will return #0, gosh x) thanks!

Comment: No. #0 is a null terminator character. A character cannot be empty.

Comment: Yes this is what i meant ^^ P return null if there's nothing

Comment: `PChar(S)` is never null. Is `S` is empty then `PChar(S)` points to a single null terminator.

Comment: @user28470: If you don't get pointers and strings, please read my articles ["Addressing pointers"](http://www.rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-pointers.html) and ["PChars: no strings attached"](http://www.rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-pchars.html).